# Why is this "invalid calling object" error?

Tags: javascript

I write the following JS and run in IE 10:

```
function test() {
    var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    document.writeln(nodes.length);
    for (var j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++) {   <=== THIS LINE!
        document.writeln(j.toString());
        }
    document.writeln("abc");
}
```

But I kept get "invalid calling object" error for the marked line.

Why?

And here is my page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>This is JS fun!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="test.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>1111</h1>   
        <h1>2222</h1>   
        <h1>3333</h1>   
        <h1>4444</h1>   
            <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="click me!" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is my screenshot:

[image]

Comment: what' the value in `nodes.length`?

Comment: It's 4. I have 4 < h1 > tags on my page. Actually, my script output this number. And the error dialog box pops up after that saying "Invalid calling object". (I turned on the IE switch to display every script error).

Comment: I tried your code in IE 10.0.9200.16384, and I don't get any error. http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/4w949/

Comment: We are using exactly the same IE. Did you turn on the display script error switch?

Comment: @smwikipedia: I run the code with the console open, and I have also tried with the error option on. There is no error, and "2 0 1 abc" ends up in the page.

Comment: I turned on the console, too. Please see my updated screenshot.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jTfFe/1/ reproduces the problem on Chrome too. Seems related to the writeln() call, it seems to invalidate your nodelist since it produces a new document.

Comment: @Joachim, is there any formal definition of this DOM object invalidation behavior?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error comes because you are running the code after the page is completed.

The first `document.writeln` call creates a new document with only the string in it. That means that the collection in `nodes` is no longer valid. It is a collection of elements in a document that doesn't exist any more, so you can't use any of the properties (like `length`) of the collection any more.

If you run the code while the page is being created, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/4w949/

Comment: it seems to be related to the valid lifetime of a document? Could you address more on it?

Comment: or, it is related to the lifetime of DOM object regarding to its containing *document*.

Comment: "*The first document.writeln call creates a new document with only the string in it. That means that the collection in nodes is no longer valid.*" - I believe that's it.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I may have figured it out.

I tried this:

```
function test() {
    var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    document.writeln(nodes.length); // 1st writeln
    nodes2 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    alert(nodes2.length);  //  <========= MARK1
    for (var j = 0; j < nodes2.length; j++) {
        alert(j);
            }
    document.writeln("abc");
}
```

No error for above code. but the **MARK1** line gives 0. Because after the **1st writeln**, the complete page content is re-constructed, **there's no < h1 > tag in the newly constructed page any more**.

And then I changed the above code to this:

```
 function test() {
    var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    document.writeln(nodes.length + "<h1>new h1</h1>");   // ADD a new < h1 > tag
    nodes2 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    alert("node2 length = " + nodes2.length);   //MARKED
    for (var j = 0; j < nodes2.length; j++) {
        alert(j);
            }
    document.writeln("abc");
}
```

Now the **MARKED** line gave me expected length, 1. Because I put a new < h1 > tag into the newly constructed document.

As to the **Invalid Calling Object** error. I think because the document is re-constructed with writeln, all the DOM objects previously obtained with the old invalidated document object will be invalided, too.

**The key is the implicit creation of a new document by document.writeln method.**

Please correct me if I am wrong.

**Thanks Guffa for the insight.**

Answer (score -7):

`j` is a variable counter, not the object.

You need `nodes.item(j).toString();`