# Invalid calling object in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-10

The following code throws "Invalid calling object" in IE10

`toString.call("a")`

can any one tell why this is happening and what is the work around for this?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990093/why-is-this-invalid-calling-object-error

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: toString is not a global function, it's a method of objects.