# What does the Javascript error: "TypeError: Invalid calling object" mean?

Tags: javascript

I've been running across the following error on IE11 intermittently and I don't understand what it's trying to telling me.

```
    TypeError: Invalid calling object
```

What does this error mean in general?
What is a calling object?

```
    object1()                // Is object1 considered a calling object?
    object2.property1        // Is object2 considered a calling object?
    object3.property2()      // What about the properties 1 and 2? Are they calling objects?
    var stuff = new Stuff()  // Is there a calling object here?
```

What makes a calling object invalid?
How is this different than the typical "undefined has no property xxx" error?

Comment: Does this question help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990093/why-is-this-invalid-calling-object-error?

Comment: The answer to the above question was: The error comes because you are running the code after the page is completed.

But I don't know what that means